# C++ function overloading between base class and inherited class

Tags: c++

consider the example below. I would have guessed that since `func` is virtual, than the decision to which implementation to call would be done in runtime according to the instance type (type B) and arguments type (short or int)

However, after running this code I got unexpected results where the pointer type only determine which function to jump, which completely break my basic assumption of polymorphism...

This lead to the question, where i can relate to the 2 func implementation as function overloading ?

can anybody tell me what cause this results ? 
thanks

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void func(short x) { printf("A::func %d\n", x); }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void func(int x) { printf("B::func %d\n", x); }
};


int main(void)
{
    int n=2;
    short m=3;

    A* a = new B;
    a->func(n);
    a->func(m);

    B* bp = new B;
    bp->func(n);
    bp->func(m);
}
//output is : 
//A::func 2
//A::func 3
//B::func 2
//B::func 3
```

Comment: Because `void func(int x)` is different from `void func(short x)`, first one doesn't overload the second, it just hidden it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a derived class has a function with the same name as one in the base class, the base class function is hidden. If you want `A::func` to be visible in `B`, write a using-declaration:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    using A::func; //here
    virtual void func(int x) { printf("B::func %d\n", x); }
};
```

Now the output is:

```
A::func 2
A::func 3
B::func 2
A::func 3
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2fdc5ce2fa81a03)